# Rewrite a simple iterative algorithm recursively

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion

It is known that in some cases an iteration can be transformed in a recursive algorithm. How can I rewrite an iteration as simple as the following one as a recursion?

```
for(i=0,i<500,i++) 
    row_multiply();
```

I realize that, as it has been pointed out, I have to try something like...

```
void recursiveSolution(int i)

    {
        raw_multiply();
        if (i< 499)
            recursiveSolution(i+ 1);
    }
```

..., but I am unsure about how to deal with the base case and how to structure coherent C code for the recursive rewrite.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Trying something related to recursion would probably be a good place to start (as would be clarifying the question). If you don't understand recursion yet, perhaps study it a bit more before tackling this. An example: [see it live](http://ideone.com/cb9aEY)

Comment: What you mean `base case`?? explain that please.

Comment: @iharob http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursive_functions_and_algorithms

Comment: @user Oh I see, you should have one situation where the function stops recursing, or in simple words, where it stops calling itself, in my sample function, that is when `count == 500`, there the recursion stops. A very illustrative recursive functions as that of the factorial calculation, google it. And if my answer was useful you can express gratitude by clicking the check mark and accepting it. After all, since the question is closed, no one else can post answers for it. Weired thing it was closed as unclear what you're asking and yet it was answered.

Answer (score 1):

May be this way?

```
void recursiveSolution(int count)
{
    raw_multiply();
    if (count < 499)
        recursiveSolution(count + 1);
}
```

and then to start it

```
recursiveSolution(0);
```

Comment: Need to check `count < 500` (as the for loop does), *before* calling `raw_multiply()` as this would do it 501 times.

Comment: `raw_multiply` needs to be inside the if too, same problem

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "and then to start it recursiveSolution(0);"?

Comment: Well, you need to do a first call to the `recursiveSolution()` function, after that it will call itself `recurse` until the condition is met.